# How to repair Elementary OS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, elementary-os

I was installing Google Chrome on my Elementary OS from installer and due to unmet dependencies I run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Don't know what happened so many removing operations started I just saw it was saying:

```
removing Pantheon-files
```

And as a result now I am not able to use Elementary OS. As every time I start Elementary it shows login screen but after logged in it just hanged nothing showing only wallpaper of login screen.

I created a live CD on USB then bootup with USB and try to install it again then installer will show repair option. I tried it but repair option is not showing.

Don't know how to get back my EOS or I will have to remove it and then reinstall it? Kindly if it's possible to repair EOS.

I am using it with Windows 7 dual boot.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, get to a terminal, and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gala pantheon-files pantheon
```

That should fix most of those issues.